# How to Install Excel Module on Python 3.6(64 bit)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tried to import the excel module but this is the result,

```
>>> pip install openpyxl==2.1.4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install openpyxl==2.1.4
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As seen, I also don't have the excel module,

```
>>>import openpyxl
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is used on the [command line](https://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything). To use it in the shell:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install', 'openpyxl==2.1.4'])
```

Or just type it into your `Terminal` or `Command Prompt` application to run the command.